# Can't use *ngFor to list an array of strings (Angular)

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor, dto

So I'm trying to exibit information from an array of strings. This array includes data that may change from one element to another (like one has contact information, the other has contact information and address, etc).

I was trying to exibit the element, but I can't. Here's my HTML snippet:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dp of consentimento.dadosPessoais">
    <li>
      {{dp}}
  </li> 
</ul>
```

I can already access other data in "consentimento", but not this array in this *ngFor. If I simply put {{consentimento.dadosPessoais}} outside of the loop I get [object Object].

The console gives me this error:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3193)
    at callHook (core.js:3109)
    at callHooks (core.js:3075)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3027)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:6264)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:6246)
    at DialogDetalharConsentimentoComponent_Template (dialog-detalhar-consentimento.component.html:62)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7449)
    at refreshView (core.js:7318)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8465)
```

I've been trying this for three days now, with zero success. I really need some help.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 
import { TemplateConsentimentoDTO } from '../../../../model/template.dto';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-dialog',
  templateUrl: './template-dialog.component.html'
})
export class TemplateDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  acao:string="";
  idEmpresa:number=0;
  idTemplate?:number; 

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TemplateDialogComponent>, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public template: TemplateConsentimentoDTO){}
  
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
      this.acao=params['acao'];
      this.idEmpresa=params['uuid'];
      this.idTemplate=params['template'];})  
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

By the way, here's the DTO for consentimento:

```
export class ConsentimentoDTO {

public id: string | undefined;
public idTemplate: number | undefined;
public idEmpresa: number | undefined;
public nomeTemplate: string | undefined;
public descricaoTemplate: string | undefined;
public cpfCoresponsavel: string | undefined;
public cpfResponsavel: string | undefined;
public dataInicio: Date | undefined;
public dataFim: Date | undefined;
public status: string | undefined;
public dadosPessoais?: string[]| undefined;
public tratamentoDados: string[]| undefined;
public template: TemplateConsentimentoDTO | undefined;
public dataSolicitacao: Date | undefined;
public solicitante: string | undefined;
public empresaSelecionada: EmpresaElement | undefined
}
```

Comment: Hi Matheus, what can you see in the log if you console.dir(...) it in the component?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, when i log the console it returns the object with its elements.

Comment: may be it’s undefined ? try ... of (consentimento.dadosPess || [])and go from there

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're experiencing is a mismatch of what you expect (the contract your `ConsentimentoDTO` is trying to enforce), and what you're actually getting (the response from your backend).

Have a look at the network traffic in your browser's devtools, and assert that the `dadosPessoais`-property of your `ConsentimentoDTO` is actually returning a `string[]`.

That would also be what you're seeing that string-interpolating the value produces `[object Object]`.

Comment: I need to display the information in this object, which I'm failing to see why it's not working.

Comment: I get that, but remember that the type-information of typescript interfaces and classes are removed at transpilation time. Hence, there's no guarantee that the server will return what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Like @andres said before. The value of

```
consentimento.dadosPessoais
```

Is not string[]
It's probably string. And this is the error you get
Because ngFor can work only on iterated objects like array and not on simple string.
Try to display outside the loop

```
consentimento.dadosPessoais[0]
```

And see if you get correct values

Answer (score 0):

I was trying different things when I found this solution that worked, if anybody is interested:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dp of consentimento.dadosPessoais">
        {{dp}}                       
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Sounds a little strange to me, since the original error said that consentimento.dadosPessoais is not an iterable and you did'nt change that

Comment: I'm also confused... Trying to see if I did anything wrong beyond that

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *ngFor in the .

**For example:**

```
<ul>
<ng-container *ngFor="let dp of consentimento.dadosPessoais">
    <li>
      {{dp}}
  </li> 
<ng-container>
</ul>
```